# how to copy columns in apache poi?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi

I want to copy columns in a excel file. Lets assume that I have an excel file like this:

[image]

as you can see C and D columns in 2. row are merged

I wanna copy C and D columns together. To do that first I'm shifting columns by using
sheet.shiftColumns(). That's working great, after that my excel file looks like this

[image]

Now my old C and D columns are in E and F. This is great. But after I shift that I also wanna copy the
E and F columns in C and D. For example I want to do this

[image]

My question is how can I copy and shift columns using apache poi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem.

First I need to find all merged regions between columns that I want to copy. To do that I use that function.

```
 private List<CellRangeAddress> getMergedRegionsBetweenTwoColumns(Sheet sheet, int startCol, int endCol) {
    List<CellRangeAddress> cellRangeAddressList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); ++i) {
        CellRangeAddress range = sheet.getMergedRegion(i);
        if (range.getFirstColumn() >= startCol && range.getLastColumn() <= endCol)
            cellRangeAddressList.add(range);
    }
    return cellRangeAddressList;
}
```

after that I need to get cells between columns that I wanna copy because I also need to copy my cells. To do that I use that function.

```
    private List<Cell> getCellsBetweenTwoColumns(Sheet sheet, Integer startCol, Integer endCol) {
    List<Cell> cellList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Row r : sheet) {
        for (int i = startCol; i <= endCol; i++) {
            Cell cell = r.getCell(i);
            if (cell != null)
                cellList.add(cell);
            // if cell equeals null than create the cell
            else{
                r.createCell(i);
                cellList.add(r.getCell(i));
            }
        }
    }
    return cellList;
}
```

After I get these lists I just need to use them. First I'm adding mergedRegions. After that I'm adding cell styles and values.

```
 List<Cell> mainCellList =getCellsBetweenTwoColumns(sheet,copyStartCol,copyEndCol);
         for (int i = 0; i < copyCount; i++) {
            for (CellRangeAddress range : cellRangeAddressList) {
            range.setFirstColumn(range.getFirstColumn() + copyColumnCount * i);
            range.setLastColumn(range.getLastColumn() + copyColumnCount * i);
            sheet.addMergedRegion(range);
            }
        List<Cell> copiedColumnsCellList = getCellsBetweenTwoColumns(sheet, copyStartCol + copyColumnCount * i, copyEndCol + copyColumnCount * i);
            for (int k = 0; k < copiedColumnsCellList.size(); k++) {
            Cell newCell = copiedColumnsCellList.get(k);
            Cell oldCell = mainCellList.get(k);
            newCell.setCellStyle(oldCell.getCellStyle());
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getStringCellValue());
            }
    }
```

copyCount represent how many copy that I need and copyColumnCount represent how many column that I wanna copy.

For more secure solution and source code you can check this repository.

https://github.com/hasankzl/apache-poi-excel-template

Answer (score 3):

Actually, all merged cells of a sheet are kept in the sheet in a list of "merged regions". You can create a merged cell e. g. using

```
sheet.addMergedRegion(rowFrom,rowTo,colFrom,colTo);
```

(see the [POI quick guide](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#MergedCells)).
And the value (data content) and format for the merged cells is technically contained in the top left cell of the merged region, the data and format of all other cell addresses of the merged region are ignored (and should be empty).
So to answer your question, you would add value `tel2` to cell C2 and set its format to horizontally centered, and then build a merged region of cells C2 and D2.

You can find examples of setting cello value and alignment in the [POI quick guide](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Alignment) as well.